# Do Hindu texts talk about memory?

Tags: consciousness, smriti, mind

Do Hindu texts talk about any of this:
How does memory work? 
Where is memory stored? 
Or, any other references related to memory are welcome.

Comment: I guess certain content in this link can help you to an extent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smriti

Comment: @S.LAKSHMINARAYAN: Sorry, but thats a wiki on Smritis, that is not helpful. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Answer given [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10954/meaning-of-citta) may help you...